# How do I disable or lower the priority of a package's keybinds?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm using a package (in this case, `MarkdownEdit`) that has keybinds that are conflicting with those of my other packages.

Is there any way that I can either disable a given package's keybinds or prevent it from overriding other keybinds?

Comment: What is the package you want to disable the keybindings in?

Comment: I'm trying to disable MarkdownEdit. It somehow destroyed the original Markdown syntax by replacing it so when I uninstall it I can't set the syntax back to Markdown because it also gets removed lol. I don't know how to reinstall the syntax but MarkdownEdit would be pretty good if I could disable its keybinds.

Comment: Yeah, I have MarkdownEdit in my `ignored_packages` just because of that.

Comment: @MattDMo Aha... thanks for the tip, I didn't know that was possible. I was able to find the old markdown syntax on the ignored packages list, so I see it was not really deleted. Thank you! It solves my immediate problem but I still want to answer the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to create a `Default (yourplatform).sublime-keymap` file in `Packages/MarkdownEditing` with an empty JSON array to override the original.

1. Create a new JSON file with the contents

   ```json
   [

   ]
   ```
2. Select **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`** (or, on macOS, **`Sublime Text → Preferences → Browse Packages…`**) to open your `Packages` folder:

   - Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` or `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages`
   - OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` or `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages`
   - Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
   - Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`

   <sup>The exact path depends on version and whether or not you upgraded from Sublime Text 3.</sup>
3. In that folder, create a folder called `MarkdownEditing`. Save your new JSON file in that folder as `Default ($YourPlatform).sublime-keymap`, where `$YourPlatform` is one of `Windows`, `OS X`, or `Linux`, depending on your actual platform.
4. Restart Sublime Text.

Now, all of the keybindings from `MarkdownEditing` *should* be nullified, giving you the originals that shipped with Sublime (or overrides you've already made).

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks for the effort @MattDMo